# Android stripe CustomerSession.addCustomerSource() not working

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's PaymentMethodActivity to add a payment source. When adding a credit card, I can debug all the way until this line of code in Stripe's AddSourceActivity:

```
        CustomerSession.getInstance().addCustomerSource(
                this,
                source.getId(),
                sourceType,
                listener);
```

The listener callbacks never get called and the progress bar on the AddSourceActivity keeps going indeterminately. This was working before, but I suspect this issue may be related to our recent backend overhaul. Could there be an issue with the api version when creating the ephemeral key?

Comment: Can you also include your code for your EphemeralKeyProvider + Backend Service code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I wasn't correctly handling the response from our backend when requesting a new ephemeral key. Originally I had deserialized the response into an object and then converted that object to a json string to pass to Stripe. I corrected the problem by directly using the string representation of the response instead of doing any unnecessary serialization steps.